# Regex for valid mentions in tweet

Tags: java, regex

I want a Regex that includes all valid mentions in a tweet @... except the @... directly after RT. Example:

RT @steve: I had an awsome day today @henrich @bulleye

=> [@henrich @bulleye]

EDIT:
I got stuck doing this `(?!RT\\s+@\\w*:)@\\w+` which gave me back
=> [@steve @henrich @bulleye]

Comment: How far did you get and where are you stuck?

Comment: Which programming language are you using ?

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [negative look-behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<!RT )(@[^ ]*)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hH9dE8/2)

Answer (score 1):

As lookbehinds need to be length fixed, usually in regex we use `\K`, but as Java doesn't have support for it, you can workaround using groups:

```
RT\\s+@\\w+|(@\\w+)
```

This way, `"RT    @steve"` will be stored in group 0, but not in group 1. While the valid mentions will be also found in group 1.